# How can I get return value from a spawned process in Erlang?

Tags: process, erlang, distributed-computing, spawn, erlang-otp

I have the following code:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

say(2,0) ->
    [1,2];

say(A,B) ->
    say(A-1,B-1).

loop(0) ->
    io:format("");

loop(Times) ->
    L = spawn(a, say, [4,2]),
    io:fwrite( "L is ~w  ~n", [L] ),
    loop(Times-1).

run() ->
    loop(4).
```

I want to have the list [1,2] in L each time function 'say' completes. However, since the pid of the process is returned instead of the list from the function say due to use of spawn, I am getting the following output:

```
L is <0.113.0>  
L is <0.114.0>  
L is <0.115.0>  
L is <0.116.0>
```

What I desire is

```
L is [1,2]
L is [1,2]
L is [1,2]
L is [1,2]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass information between processes, you use `!` to send a message to another process's mailbox, and you use a `receive clause` to extract a message from a process mailbox.  Here is an example:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

%% Worker process:
say(From, 2, 0) ->
    From ! {self(), [1,2]};
say(From, A, B) ->
    say(From, A-1, B-1).


%%  Main process:
loop(0) ->
    ok;
loop(Times) ->
    Pid = spawn(a, say, [self(), 4, 2]),
    receive  %%waits here for result before spawning another process--no concurrency
        {Pid, Result} ->
            io:fwrite( "L is ~w  ~n", [Result] )
    end,
    loop(Times-1).


%%  Test:
run() ->
    loop(4).
```

In the shell:

```
7> c(a).   
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

8> a:run().
L is [1,2]  
L is [1,2]  
L is [1,2]  
L is [1,2]  
ok

9>
```

Or, you can spawn all the processes, then read the results as they come in:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

%% Worker process:
say(From, 2, 0) ->
    From ! [1,2];
say(From, A, B) ->
    say(From, A-1, B-1).


%%  Main process:
loop(N) ->
    loop(N, N).

loop(0, Times) ->
    display_results(Times);
loop(N, Times) ->
    spawn(a, say, [self(), 4, 2]),
    loop(N-1, Times).
 
display_results(0) -> 
    ok;
display_results(Times) ->
    receive
        Result ->
            io:format("L is ~w~n", [Result])
    end,
    display_results(Times-1).

%%  Test:
run() ->
    loop(4).
```

To ensure that you only `receive` messages from the processes that you spawned, you can do this:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

%% Worker process:
say(From, 2, 0) ->
    From ! {self(), [1,2]};
say(From, A, B) ->
    say(From, A-1, B-1).


%%  Main process:
loop(Times) ->
    loop(Times, _Pids=[]).

loop(0, Pids) ->
    display_results(Pids);
loop(Times, Pids) ->
    Pid = spawn(a, say, [self(), 4, 2]),
    loop(Times-1, [Pid|Pids]).


display_results([]) -> 
    ok;
display_results([Pid|Pids]) ->
    receive
        {Pid, Result} ->
            io:format("L is ~w~n", [Result])
    end,
    display_results(Pids).

%%  Test:
run() ->
    loop(4).
```

There are some risks when using a `receive` like that:  if a worker process crashes before it sends the message to your main process, then your main process will be stuck indefinitely in the receive while waiting for a message to arrive from the crashed process.  One solution: use a timeout in the receive.  Another: use spawn_monitor().

Answer (score 2):

You need to use messages (or signals) for that, as the code is running in a separate process.

I like to use spawn_monitor in that case:

```
1> {Pid, MonitorReference} = spawn_monitor(fun() -> timer:sleep(10000), exit({ok, [1,2]}) end),
1> receive {'DOWN', MonitorReference, process, Pid, {ok, Result}} -> Result end.
```

Keep in mind that you can `receive` for several messages at the same time or you can just receive them in order (leaving the out of order ones in the mailbox). So you can spawn several threads and wait for all of them to be finished, gathering the results:

```erlang
work(Workload) ->
    JobReference = make_ref(),
    PidReferences = [spawn_monitor(fun() -> exit({JobReference, do_stuff(WorkSlice)}) end) || WorkSlice <- Workload],
    [receive
        {'DOWN', Reference, process, Pid, {JobReference, Result}} -> Result;
        {'DOWN', Reference, process, Pid, Result} -> {error, Result}
    end || {Pid, Reference} <- PidReferences].
```